# da error al actualizar el modulo

Tags: xml, odoo

hice unos cambios en el modulo que estoy pero a la hora de hacer upgrade en el modulo me manda que en miarchivo XML hay un error y que no puede parcear la informacion y no pèrmite actualizar el modulo y ver los cambios que hice porque da error en esta parte del XML

Adjunto codigo

```
''''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
<record id="view_presupuesto_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Vista formulario de presupuesto de peliculas</field>
    <field name="model">presupuesto</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="clasificiacion"/>

                </group>
                <group>
                    <field name="puntuacion"/>
                    <field name="active"/>
                </group>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>

</record>
</odoo>'''
```

en la consola al actualizar el  modulo dice que hay un error en este codigo la verdad no puedo ver que error tiene
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consola arroja que ahi esta el error al darle upgrade al modulo no encuentro el error no se si sea de sintaxis o este mal identado el codigo leas adjunte la imagen de error que da en la terminal

Comment: Hola. En este tipo de errores debes de poner toda la traza. Por favor copia y pega aquí toda la traza del error. El problemea generalmente se lista más arriba de donde estas mostrando todo el error.

Comment: listo muchas gracias fue unn error nde escritura